# How to call backbone.model's this inside d3.drag context

Tags: javascript, d3.js, backbone.js

I have the following backbone model with a d3.drag functionality. I cannot call the model's `this` inside the d3's context.

I came across with solutions for similar questions by defining a variable `model=this` and calling by `model.draw..` but how can I add it inside d3's drag?

```
   DataMapper.Models.Anchor = Backbone.Model.extend({
                defaults: {
                        //...
                },
                initialize : function(){
                        d3.select("#anchor").call(this.dragAnchor); //make the #anchor draggable
                },
                dragAnchor: d3.drag()
                        .on("start", function (d) {
                            console.log("something"); //it prints
                            var thisDragY = this.drawSomething(a,b,c); 
                            // this.drawSomething is not a function
                            // because inside d3.drag(), 'this' refers to #anchor
                            // what I want to refer is the model
                        })
                        .on("drag", function (d) {})
                        .on("end", function (d) {}),
                drawSomething: function (parent, cx, cy) {
                   //code
                }
            });
```

Is there a way to use underscore's `bind` to achieve my desired goal? [Link to a useful article](http://blog.bigbinary.com/2011/08/18/understanding-bind-and-bindall-in-backbone.html).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution was found by a team member - to call the drag as a function.

```
   DataMapper.Models.Anchor = Backbone.Model.extend({
                defaults: {
                        //...
                },
                initialize : function(){
                        d3.select("#anchor").call(this.dragAnchor()); //make the #anchor draggable
                },
                dragAnchor: function(){
                        var self=this;
                        return d3.drag()
                           .on("start", function (d) {
                               console.log("something"); //it prints
                               var thisDragY = self.drawSomething(a,b,c); 
                           })
                           .on("drag", function (d) {})
                           .on("end", function (d) {}),
                drawSomething: function (parent, cx, cy) {
                   //code
                }
            });
```